# com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'name'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

I have text 800 characters I do query

```
UPDATE `users` SET `name`="800 characters...

1 row(s) affected
```

and it works, name type is VARCHAR(2500) then I use spring boot with hibernate.

```
User user = userRepository.getOne(1);
user.setName("800 characters...);
userRepository.save(user)
```

and I get this error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: 
Data too long for column 'name'
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: share ur column description. it ill  happe when u r inserting value more than column data size

Comment: it is VARCHAR(2500)

Answer (score 1):

It is related with the audited tables of envers.
Query works because it does not use envers.

Manually updated the type of the audited table fixed issue